# Mysql service issue

Tags: mysql

I want to change the location of my mysql.sock file for that i am trying to stop the mysql and then editing the `my.cnf` file but i am getting a message

**abdul@OSS-240:~$ service mysql stop**

> stop: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call",
>   sender=":1.62" (uid=1001 pid=3159 comm="stop)
>   interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Stop" error
>   name="(unset)" requested_reply=0 destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart"
>   (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init"))

what is the issue.

Comment: I wonder if the symbolic link to /etc/init.d/mysql is broken? Can you post the output of 'ls -l /etc/init.d/mysql' please? Also do you have any luck stopping MySQL if you run 'sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop'?

Comment: @TomMac:   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 2011-09-09 15:24 /etc/init.d/mysql -> /lib/init/upstart-job        :by using sudo i was able to do my work but i really want to know whats the issue

Comment: @TomMac:  sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop : i used this and it works

Comment: which version of Ubuntu are you running on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds as though user 'abdul' does not have the required permissions to stop and start MySQL Server. Either grant these permissions (probably not advisable for the sake of security) or execute the stop and start command as root.

Comment: I also think same but in the early version of ubuntu i was able to start and stop the services as user "abdul".